# How to sort Date in Datagridview on Header Click VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, winforms, datagridview

I know this is a very similar question and a lot of question are out there on the internet.
But please check to it once.

**What I am doing?**
I created a query as follows
`Select Document_No AS 'DOCUMENT NO.', FORMAT(CAST(Trans_Date as date),'dd-MM-yyyy') as 'DATE', Party_Name as 'PARTY NAME', Amount as 'AMOUNT', Description as 'DESCRIPTION' from FAVCDPTRAN`

Now I fetch data from the query and set it to the datatable say `dt`.
I set this `dt` to datagridview say`DGVHelp` such as `DGVHelp.DataSource = dt`

Now I want to sort date on Header Click. But it reacts like a string and sort it. I want to sort it as a Date.
I tried many things on the internet but nothing achieved.

Things I tried : 
This is done after `DGVHelp.DataSource = dt`

1. `DGVHelp.Columns("DATE").DefaultCellStyle.Format = "dd-MM-yyyy"`
2. `DGVHelp.Columns("DATE").ValueType = GetType(Date)`
3. `DGVHelp.Item(1,1).Value = CDate(DGVHelp.Item(1,1).Value)`.

Its obv. the 3rd one gave me an error as data is set through DataSource.

Is there any way that I can set the column datatype as Date and it automatically converts the string date to Datetime date?
Else I tried to remove Format in Query and it worked but I get results in `yyyy-MM-dd` so is there any way to get custom Format?
`Format` in Query again changes it to string Data Type I guess.

I changed query as requested by Jimi as following : 
`Select Document_No AS 'DOCUMENT NO.', CAST(Trans_Date as date) as 'DATE', Party_Name as 'PARTY NAME', Amount as 'AMOUNT', Description as 'DESCRIPTION' from FAVCDPTRAN`

Comment: Don't convert to string, use the Date/Time format only. If you want a custom format for presentation purposes, use the Format property of the corresponding DGV Column. Unless you're forced to by your database, don't use stings to store Date/Time values.

Comment: I know but how shall I change its format in datagridview after setting datatable as its datasource??

Comment: I think I've just said that. Set the Format of the DefaultCellStyle of the corresponding Column of your DGV. Are the Columns auto-generated at run-time? Then, after setting the DataSource, change the Format to e.g., `DGVHelp.Columns("DATE").DefaultCellStyle.Format = CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture.DateTimeFormat.ShortDatePattern`, like what you're doing now. What matters is that the source Column, coming from the query, returns Date/Time objects, not strings. Is your database designed to store strings or Date/Time values? What kind of database are you using? <= You should add the Tag.

Comment: I did the same as you said but still how to get format 'dd-MM-yyyy'? @Jimi

Comment: Setting `[The Column].DefaultCellStyle.Format = "dd-MM-yyyy"`. Are you loading strings or Date/Time objects from the database? As mentioned, this is the only thing that counts. The rest is just trivial formatting. Date/Time objects are only formatted for presentation, e.g., to adapt to a specific Culture representation of the Date/Time. The storage type doesn't change. A Date/Time doesn't have *format*.

Comment: Na I am loading Date/Time objects from Database and not strings. But This `[The Column].DefaultCellStyle.Format = "dd-MM-yyyy"` doesn't help. Format is still 'yyyy-MM-dd' but sorting is done properly now @Jimi

Comment: You cannot have Date/Time formatted as `yyyy-MM-dd` if you have explicitly set a different Format, as `dd-MM-yyyy`. That's means that you're re-setting the Format somewhere else. Check your code.

Comment: I am getting `yyyy-MM-dd` from the database itself. If I run the query in ssms it results also returns `yyyy-MM-dd` Mind that I cast the data to Date and not DateTime in query and no `Format` is used. @Jimi

Comment: Also Check end of the question I added the query I am using now. If you want then I can add result of the Database. @Jimi

Comment: Oh wait. I am using a View not a table in query. Lemme check all again.

Comment: Okay the table I am using has column `Trans_Date` which datatype is `date`. on running table directly as `select * from table1` the `Trans_Date` format returns as 'yyyy-MM-dd'. Is it because of collation of database?@Jimi

Comment: I agree but thats what I am getting in result. and can we take this to chat? @Jimi

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/229590/discussion-between-bonny-and-jimi).

Comment: @Jimi thats sql server RDBMS. Shall I tag Sql Server to Question?

Comment: I removed the cast, still the same answer. And what exactly is database reference or database type? @Jimi

Comment: Okay, I answer everything, I am using SQL Server 14.0.1000.169. -- Data Type of Column Trans_Date is `Date` in the table in SQL Server @Jimi

Comment: Then, if your query is `SELECT * FROM [SomeTable]`, you get DateTime objects in your DataTable. You can format the UI output as needed, as already mentioned. The `date` data type has a `yyyy-mm-dd` string literal format in SQL Server. Its storage data (3 bytes) is mapped to DateTime when you get the results from the query. It's important to  specify what kind of tools you're using, so you - as always - need to post the code that preforms the queries and generates .Net objects. It would also clarify whether you're using, e.g., a Stored Procedure etc.

Comment: I'm just using a query and that I posted above. Now I don't remember if I have made any format for UI output needed. I just want to make `yyyy-MM-dd` to format `dd-MM-yyyy` and with its sorting work properly. So I posted everything you said. The query, the vb.net Code, Sql version number but still its not working.  @Jimi

Comment: I still didn't get the answer and still searching the internet. A help would be better @Jimi

Comment: It appears that, as often happens, you're confusing the Date value with its presentation (the same applies to other *numbers* <- the Date is number): don't format your Date Column in the query, returning a string. It's as simple as that. -- Do you need a specific format to present your Date Column (not the standard format generated by `Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture`, the format determined by the current culture)? Then set the `Format` Property of the Date Column. Again, as simple as that. Remembering that the Format you see in the UI is just a presentation of the value, not the value.